# Vue JS 2 component not displaying data after using v-if in Nuxt JS 2 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm working in a Nuxt JS 2 project and have built a component called `Calculator`. This is loaded into my page which contains a HTML table. I have a button in the page that toggles the calculator, the variable to toggle is a boolean `isCalculatorShown`.

When my calculator component is initially toggled on everything works, but when the `isCalculatorShown` variable then gets switched from `true` back to `false` (essentially destroying the component) and then toggled on again, everything works apart from the output to the page of my `formulas` object.

Console logging in the `calculateCells` method shows me the correct values, yet trying to do `this.formulas.*` doesn't update the one inside `data()`, what am I missing, here's my Calculator component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="calculator-wrapper">
    <b-button @click="closeCalculator" pill variant="white" size="sm" class="btn-close shadow">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="22" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="text-secondary">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 12H9m12 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
      </svg>
    </b-button>
    <div class="sums p-1">
      <article>
        <div class="d-none d-md-flex">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal bg-transparent">
            <li class="list-group-item">Sum: {{ formulas.sum }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Avg: {{ formulas.avg }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Min: {{ formulas.min }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Max: {{ formulas.max }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Count: {{ formulas.count }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex d-md-none">
          <select name="cell-calculations" class="custom-select">
            <option>Sum: {{ formulas.sum }}</option>
            <option>Avg: {{ formulas.avg }}</option>
            <option>Min: {{ formulas.min }}</option>
            <option>Max: {{ formulas.max }}</option>
            <option>Count: {{ formulas.count }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </article>
      <div class="p-1">
        <b-button @click="clear" variant="dark" size="sm">Clear</b-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    isCalculatorShown: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    dataScope: {
      default: 'td',
      type: String
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      calculator: null,
      table: null,
      cells: null,
      cellValues: [],
      formulas: {
        sum: 0,
        avg: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 0,
        count: 0
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.initCalculator()

    for (const cell of this.cells) {
      cell.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        this.getCellValue(cell)
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {

    /*
    ** Init calculator
    */
    initCalculator () {
      this.calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator-wrapper')
      this.table = document.getElementById('main-report')

      if (!this.table) return

      this.cells = this.table.querySelectorAll(this.dataScope)
    },

    /*
    ** Calculate value of selected table cells
    */
    calculateCells (val) {
      // TODO: this.formulas never seems to update one in data() after component v-if toggled
      this.formulas.sum = val.map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0).toFixed(2)
      this.formulas.avg = (val.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / val.length).toFixed(2)
      this.formulas.min = Math.min(...val)
      this.formulas.max = Math.max(...val) || 0
      this.formulas.count = val.length || 0
    },

    getCellValue (cell) {
      const SANITISED_REGEX = /^£|,|%|s|\([^)]*\) */g
      const trimmedCellValue = cell.innerText.trim().replace(/^-£|£-/g, '-')
      const firstCellValue = this.getFirstCellValue(trimmedCellValue)

      if (firstCellValue) {
        const sanitisedValue = firstCellValue.replace(SANITISED_REGEX, '')

        if (
          this.isNumeric(sanitisedValue) &&
          !cell.classList.contains('highlight-cell')
        ) {
          this.cellValues.push(sanitisedValue)
          cell.classList.add('highlight-cell')
          this.calculateCells(this.cellValues.map(Number))
        }
      } else {
        if (
          this.isNumeric(trimmedCellValue.replace(SANITISED_REGEX, '')) &&
          !cell.classList.contains('highlight-cell')
        ) {
          cell.classList.add('highlight-cell')
          this.cellValues.push(trimmedCellValue.replace(SANITISED_REGEX, ''))
          this.calculateCells(this.cellValues.map(Number))
        }
      }

    },

    /*
    ** Check if selected cell is a number
    */
    isNumeric (str) {
      if (typeof str != 'string') return false
      return !isNaN(str) && !isNaN(parseFloat(str))
    },

    /*
    ** Return first value if there are multiple within the table cell
    */
    getFirstCellValue (cell) {
      return cell.split('  ')[0]
    },

    /*
    ** Close calculator
    */
    closeCalculator () {
      this.$emit('onClose', true)
      this.clear()
    },

    /*
    ** Clear any selected values
    */
    clear () {
      this.cellValues = []

      this.formulas.sum = 0
      this.formulas.avg = 0
      this.formulas.min = 0
      this.formulas.max = 0
      this.formulas.count = 0

      for (const cell of this.cells) {
        cell.classList.remove('highlight-cell')
        cell.removeEventListener('click', this.getCellValue)
      }

    }

  }
}
</script>
```

And it's loaded at the page level with:

```html
<Calculator v-if="isCalculatorShown" @onClose="isCalculatorShown = false" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure but your app's reactivity is definitely breaking. One thing that sticks out is the use of the document interface, e.g. `document.querySelector`, `getElementById`, etc. This is bad practice. Vue should manage the entire DOM for you.  Direct access/manipulation _can_ break reactivity.  I would refactor these lines of code to be more "Vue-like", which you can 100% do.  Instead of querySelect, you should be using template refs and/or props. Instead of add/remove eventListeners, use [Vue's event handling system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events)

Comment: Thanks for this. Wondering why it would work initially on load and then stop working thereafter?